# Reverse for 'contact' not found. 'contact' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I get this error django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'contact' not found. 'contact' is not a valid view function or pattern name.. What could I be doing wrong, new to django

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
                    path(r'', views.firstpage, name='index'),
                    path(r"contact/", views.contact, name='contact'),

]
```

views.py

```
def firstpage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

index.html

```
<ul class="menu-list">
                    <li><a href="">Solution</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}" >Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py file instead of this -

```
 path(r"contact/", views.contact, name='contact'),
```

Use this,

```
 path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

Comment: I still get the same error.Reverse for 'contact' not found. 'contact' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Add from django.conf.urls import url at top of file in import section then change url pattern like this -url(r'^contact$', views.contact, name='contact'),